# Mercurial: "branching" on file level?

Tags: mercurial, branch, development-environment

My use case is this:

I am developing in different environments, but on the same code base. 
  In order to be able to compile I have different Visual Studio solution 
  files which reflect the different developing environments.
  (different development environments: Win XP / Win 7 
                                       -> 3rd party libraries in different locations etc)

What I would like to do is to keep the code base in synch between the both environemts
  (i.e.: .cs, .xml, .config files etc), but having different solution files.

Currently what I do is push / pull changes between the repositories in the two 
environments. 
But at the moment I do not know how to exclude the solution files from being 
pushed / pulled.

The solution files, of course, change over time as well (e.g. when adding files). 
  These changes are much more infrequent so that I'd rather do changes like that twice
  rather than repairing the solution files each time I try to sync the source code base.

How can this best be done with Mercurial? Is it possible at all?

Thanks,

Jabba

Comment: You cannot prevent files from being pushed because you're not pushing files, you're pushing changesets.

As such, you'll always push the entire changeset every time, so if the changeset contains changes to your solution file, you'll push those changes as well. Would having multiple solution files work?

Comment: The different files are files required by Visual Studio or are used by your application?

Comment: @Lasse: Yes, multiple solution files might work. I'll try that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @brandizzi: As a concrete example: I use NUnit. In my development environment at home the Nunit dlls reside in a different place than at work. So I have different references to these dlls in the solution files. After pushing changes from one environment to the other I have to adapt all NUnit references in the solution files. I guess that could be automated via scripts, but, of course, it would be preferrable if Mecurial had support for this somehow. (And NUnit is just an example.)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a problem of OSD (operating system dependent) files. Many bad source control systems (which lack file level branching) handle them through special OSD directories and setup scripts. Where you simply store files for different platform or computer setup in different directory and use script to adjust it before commit and after checkout.

I'm personally in favor of symlinks in relevant places which you simply repoint to the correct location with files for your current platform. It is not ideal, but better than excluding those files from version control altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Store "skeleton" files in repo, modify for every location solution-files using local MQ-patches (and use MQ, yes)